# Restrict OSMDroid scrolling to a specific bounding box & zoom level

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, offline, osmdroid

I have tiles downloaded from Mobac tool, with the source being Openstreet mapQuest.

Given that we may not have tiles for all positions at a higher zoom level, when we scroll, areas that are missing tiles result in a null grid or stretched images of lower zoom-level tiles.

**How can I restrict scrolling to only a given bounding box and zoom level?**

Comment: i am sure the question is useful ,i am curious to know the reason of downvote, is it unclear or the answer is already available .

Comment: A popular search engines mentions at least `BoundedMapView` and `setScrollableAreaLimit()` as well as `setMinZoomLevel()` and `setMaxZoomLevel()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing MapListener interface, I overrode the OnZoom function. Depending upon current zoomlevel and the points visible on screen, the scrollable boundingbox can be set by calling `mapView.setScrollableAreaLimit`.